# Benefits of using method .append() in Python

Tags: python, list, append

I just found out that you can do this

```
objecttoaddto = [1,2,3,4]
objecttoaddto +=[5,6]
```

Which is simpler than

```
objecttoaddto = [1,2,3,4]
objecttoaddto.append(5)
objecttoaddto.append(6)
```

Especially if I want to add multiple elements/objects.

Why would I ever want to use the method .append() instead of just += ?

Comment: You use it when you only have one item to add, rather than a list.

Comment: FYI, those are lists, not arrays.

Comment: @Barmar But why would I want a specific way to add only one item, if there is already a way to add one or multiple? That's just duplicate functionality, and it doesn't even save me any character/typing.

Comment: If you only want to add 1 item, you would have to first put it into a list, then concatenate the lists. That list is unnecessary.

Comment: Adding 1 item at a time is much more common than concatenating lists.

Comment: += should be faster than multiple append. But there are cases when you have your items one at a time and need to append nonetheless